# REST web service-response not in json format with addition of WNS jar

Tags: json

I got REST response properly in JSON format in postman
eg :

```
 Input -{
"accessToken" : "123",
"salaryCode": "11",
"date" : "01072016"
}

Output : {
  "errMessage": "",
  "status": "Success",
  "swipeDetails": "0911,  0919,  0939,  1003,  1234,  1308,  1331,  1332,  1556,  1619,  1839,  1842"
}
```

But when I add new dependency for windows push notification in pom.xml like

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fernandospr</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-wns</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

i will get below output which not in json format-

```
<HashMap>
    <errMessage></errMessage>
    <status>Success</status>
    <swipeDetails>0911,  0919,  0939,  1003,  1234,  1308,  1331,  1332,  1556,  1619,  1839,  1842</swipeDetails>
</HashMap>
```

anybody pl suggest cause for this or alternative solution for WNS.